# Django Web Scraping

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have a Django project that I am working on, to scrape data from a website and display it on the Django page. The page however takes about 10 seconds to load, because accessing the data from another website isn't quick. My solution to this would be to create a model that stores the data, then updates itself in the background, but I don't know how to execute this. I am also open to other options, I'm pretty new at this :)

This is currently what my code looks like, which is too slow:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests, json

def getNums():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time, urllib.request, requests

    url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    numberContainers = soup.select(".maincounter-number")

    spanTags = []
    for container in numberContainers:
        spanTags.append(container.findChildren("span"))

    numbers = []
    for container in spanTags:
        numbers.append(container[0].decode_contents())

    return numbers

def homeView(request):
    numbers = getNums()
    cases = numbers[0]
    deaths = numbers[1]
    recovered = numbers[2]
    context = {
        "cases": cases,
        "deaths": deaths,
        "recovered": recovered,
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into multithreading I came upon this answer:

```
def getNums():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time, urllib.request, requests

    url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    numberContainers = soup.select(".maincounter-number")

    spanTags = []
    for container in numberContainers:
        spanTags.append(container.findChildren("span"))

    numbers = []
    for container in spanTags:
        numbers.append(container[0].decode_contents())

    data = Data.objects.all()[0]
    data.cases = numbers[0]
    data.deaths = numbers[1]
    data.recovered = numbers[2]
    data.save()
    print("i got here")

def homeView(request):
    t1 = Thread(target=getNums)
    t1.start()
    data = Data.objects.all()[0]
    context = {
        "cases": data.cases,
        "deaths": data.deaths,
        "recovered": data.recovered
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```